# Не отправляют данные с формы на REST контроллер.Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, html, jquery, ajax, rest

Есть контроллер с тремя методами.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/listProducts")
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }
    /*produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}*/
    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> listProducts() {
        return productService.getListProducts();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productService.saveProduct(product);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateProduct")
    public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return updateProduct(product);
    }
}
```

Когда из формы передаю данные на урл - `listProducts/create` происходит такая ошибка:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:

Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Так передаю данные из формы на контроллер:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $('table');
                var loadDataFromDB = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: LIST_PRODUCTS,
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        success: function (result) {
                            for(var i in result) {
                                var str = "<tr>";
                                for(var prop in result[i]){
                                    str += "<td>" + result[i][prop] + "</td>";
                                }
                                str += "</tr>";
                                table.append(str);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Exception on out");
                        }
                    });


                $('#btn').click(function () {
                sendAjaxForm();
                console.log(response);
            });

            function sendAjaxForm() {

                var DATA = {
                    name: $("#name").val(),
                    description: $("#description").val(),
                    create_date: $("#create_date").val(),
                    place_storage: $("#place_storage").val(),
                    reserved: $("#reserved").val()
                };


                $.ajax({
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS + "/create",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        loadDataFromDB();
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Exception in send" + response)
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Надо передавать с типом контента json

Comment: @RomanC, я переписал, но ошибка та же. Изменил вопрос, с "исправленным" вариантом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запрос проходил в формате "aplication/json" нужно помимо `dataType = "json"`, указать `contentType="aplication/json"`